# I want to pivot table in SQL and save data en temp table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, pivot, pivot-table, temp-tables

My SQL query is:

```
SELECT SUM([CurrentAmount]) AS Sums, Description 
FROM [xyz] 
WHERE CheckDate = '20191129' 
GROUP BY Description
```

it results in this output:

```
| Sums | Description |
| ---- | ----------- |
|  122 | abc         |
|  233 | xyz         |
```

but I want:

```
| abc | xyz | lmn | abk | nkf | etc |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 122 | 233 | 111 | 222 | 111 | 012 |
```

Comment: Can you specify (and tag) which system you're using? The correct answer could be dependent on that. e.g. [tag:sql-server], [tag:mysql], [tag:postgresql], [tag:ms-access], etc.

Comment: Also, please include any version-specific tags such as [tag:sql-server-2016] for example.

Comment: i am using Ms SQL 2012

Comment: Have you searched for similar questions? For instance, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10404455/92389) may apply to your situation.

Comment: DEAR sir i get the disired resluts but i want to save that result to temp table is it possible we can save selected data to temp table where column are dynamic ?/